How to define a group action on a finite dimensional complex vector space for finite abelian group G?
For any finite abelian group $G$ we can define a character $\chi:G\to \mathbb{C} $ that is homomorphism. Also $G \equiv \hat{G}:=$ set of all characters of $G$. Now, if we have a finite dimensional complex vector space $V$. A group action is a map from $G\times V\to V$. Is there any obvious way to define a group action from $G$ to $V$? or How can we define a group action on $V$ using characters?

Given a character $\chi$, there is a very natural action: $g.v=\chi(g)v$.

The homomorphism χ should be into the multiplicative group of nonzero complex numbers, and not into the additive group. These are the 1-dimensonal characters.

There are many many many ways of defining a group action of $G$ on $V$, but most are just silly. What you should be interested in (and probably are though you don't say it) is actions in which each $g\in G$ respects the structure of $V$ and acts as a linear transformation on $V$. That is, you really want homomorphisms $G\to GL(V)$. Then it is an easy theorem of linear algebra that $V$ is a direct sum of one-dimensional $G$-invariant subspaces, on each of which $G$ acts as $g:v\mapsto \chi(g)\cdot v$ where $\chi$ is one of your (1-diml) characters.

@ancientmathematician Thank you very much. I was looking for this explanation.

@PVanchinathan, Yes, I was considering non-zero. Its a typo in the question. Thank you for figuring out.

Take map $G \times V \rightarrow V$ given by $(q,v)\mapsto o(g)v$.
